# build Golang release binaries for Github

Tags: github, go

I'm looking for ideas on how to easily build binaries for common platforms for a Golang project, for release on Github.

I already know how to manually do releases, using Github's instructions at [Creating Releases](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-releases/). And I'm currently doing releases using [aktau/github-release](https://github.com/aktau/github-release), but this requires manually logging into different machines (OSX, Linux, Windows) and doing the release.

Benedikt Lang has [blogged](http://www.blang.io/2014/07/28/travis-release-golang.html) about using [Travis-CI](https://travis-ci.org/) (which I'm yet to experiment with). But I presume the public Travis will only build binaries for Linux.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do I understand you correct, you interest in cross-compile? http://dave.cheney.net/2012/09/08/an-introduction-to-cross-compilation-with-go

Comment: The idea is to make cross-compiled binaries for all platforms and make the release on github

Comment: Yes, sounds likes cross-compilation.

Comment: FWIW Travis CI can also do Mac OS X builds: http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/osx-ci-environment/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for all the suggestions and answers that were given. **Cross-compilation** was what I was looking for, and [Dave Cheney's blog post](http://dave.cheney.net/2013/07/09/an-introduction-to-cross-compilation-with-go-1-1) was a good start.

However I found a better solution - [laher/goxc](https://github.com/laher/goxc) - "a build tool for Go, with a focus on cross-compiling, packaging and deployment". It was inspired by Dave Cheney's work, and also includes deploy tools for Github - just what I was looking for. (For example, I used it to release [soniah/awsenv](https://github.com/soniah/awsenv))

Answer (score 4):

You are most likely right about the Travis CI only building in Linux as go cross-compilation requires you to build from source and build other go executables.  Like RoninDev suggested, I would suggest that you setup your own cross-compilation build environment by following the blog post:

http://dave.cheney.net/2012/09/08/an-introduction-to-cross-compilation-with-go

It is quite easy, and only takes about 10 minutes.  After you have that, a build tool such as Jenkins will give you the controls to kick off a build for the desired platforms (Mac, Windows, Linux, etc) and then push out git releases for each one.

Answer (score 2):

I created [goreleaser](https://github.com/goreleaser/goreleaser) to do just that.

You can try it out if you want :)